# How to put files into Android/Data/com.mycomp.myapp?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I'm new to Android. Switched from .NET WPF/Windows Forms. I have some JSON  files in my project. How to put them in the future **/Android/data/[packagename]/**
folder? In .NET WPF you just open properties for that file and select *copy to application folder* or so. Probably there is the same method in Android Studio, isn't it?

Comment: Have you done any research on Android Studio before asking this question? There are multiple ways of placing a JSON file into your project. One being in the `assets/` folder or in `res/raw/`. Just a tip, but first Google your questions and don't assume Android Studio is like .NET WPF

Comment: "Probably there is the same method in Android Studio, isn't it?" -- no, sorry. Put the file in `assets/`, then use `AssetManager` and `open()` at runtime to get an `InputStream`, which you can use to copy to your desired location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put them in the assets folder if you just want them to be read accessible.  If you need them to be writable, you'd put them in assets and then copy them to the filesystem on first run.

Comment: They've in the assets and they do not appear in Android/data/[packagename] folder.

Comment: Right-  you have to move them there from assets on first run if you absolutely need them on the file system.  Or you can just use them from assets if you only need to read them